# サーバー側が PHP などの動的なコンテンツでなくとも「Ajax」は成り立ちますか？

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajaxはwebサーバにhtmlと、htmlファイルでhello_ajax.jsというjsファイルを読み込んで、
そのhello_ajax.jsがイベント発生時に、var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();～の処理を実行さえすれば
最低限成り立つと考えてよろしいでしょうか？

つまりphpの部分は特に必須ではなく、プラスアルファの機能としてついているだけでWEBサーバ自体は必須なものの、
サーバサイトのプログラムファイル自体はまったく必須ではないと考えてよいでしょうか？

また使うWEBサーバもnodejsのローカルサーバでもcloud9でも、ロリポのスタンダードプランのサーバでもどんなものでも、
WEBサーバでさえあれば問題なく使えるのがajaxと考えてよいでしょうか？

最後に下記のように聞いたのですが、XMLHttpRequestオブジェクトのなかにあるメソッドを使うとサーバとの通信ができるという事でしょうか？
つまりXMLHttpRequestオブジェクトとはサーバとの通信用のメソッドが収められている箱、オブジェクトという事でよいでしょうか？

> Ajax（Asynchronous JavaScript + XML）とは、ひとことで言うならば、「JavaScript（XMLHttpRequestオブジェクト）を利用してサーバー側と非同期通信を行い、受け取った結果をDOM経由でページに反映するしくみ」です。

Comment: 引用元を明示しておいて下さるようお願いします。

Comment: JS本格入門の引用になります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> つまりphpの部分は特に必須ではなく、プラスアルファの機能としてついているだけでWEBサーバ>自体は必須なものの、
>   サーバサイトのプログラムファイル自体はまったく必須ではないと考えてよいでしょうか？

Ajax は JavaScript の XMLHttpRequest を使って非同期にリモートサーバと通信を行い、得た結果を使って動的に画面を書き換える手法の事を言うので

- 自前のサーバでなくてもよい
- 別に php でなくても他の言語でもよい
- なんならサーバ側の静的テキストファイルでもよい

となります。実際にサーバ側で定期的に更新される静的な JSON ファイルを読み込んで画面を構成する事はありますし、それも Ajax です。

> 最後に下記のように聞いたのですが、XMLHttpRequestオブジェクトのなかにあるメソッドを使うとサーバとの通信ができるという事でしょうか？

はい。ただし通信できる相手は基本、そのコンテンツ(HTML)を貰ってきたサーバに限ります。これについては他のサーバと通信できる方法(JSONPだとか、CORSだとか)がありますが、ひとまず最初の理解としては必要ないかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

＞＞＞
Ajax は JavaScript の XMLHttpRequest を使って非同期にリモートサーバと通信を行い、得た結果を使って動的に画面を書き換える手法の事を言うので

    自前のサーバでなくてもよい
    別に php でなくても他の言語でもよい
    なんならサーバ側の静的テキストファイルでもよい

となります。実際にサーバ側で定期的に更新される静的な JSON ファイルを読み込んで画面を構成する事はありますし、それも Ajax です。



WEBサーバの機能さえあれば、ローカルサーバでもなんでもOK

php、nodejsなどサーバサイドのプログラムがなくても、実行できる。

サーバサイドにhtmlとajax.jsのみがあればOK

という事ですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: XMLHttpRequestオブジェクトのなかにあるメソッドを使うとサーバとの通信ができるという事
でよさそうですね。
このメソッドがサーバにinput内のテキストを送って、サーバがそれを受け取って、htmlファイルに組み込んで、
クライアントに送り、ブラウザにそのhtmlが表記されるという感じですかね？
ただ部分的に変更するだけなのでもしかするとhtmlに組み込む作業自体がなくて、
inputないのテキストを加工してその加工データだけを送り返して、ブラウザ上でhtmlに組み込むのですかね？

Comment: サーバとの間で何を通信するかによりますが、サーバ側とブラウザ側を分業する為に一般的に JSON を用いる事が多いです。ブラウザ側は JSON をパースすれば JavaScript のオブジェクトとして扱えるのでそれをループさせて表を作ったりします。サーバとブラウザ間で部分的な HTML を送りつける pjax という手法もありますが、それは一旦 JSON を用いた Ajax を知ったあとの方が良いと思います。

Comment: 下記が一番重要な点なのでお手数ですが確認させてください。正しいでしょうか？

＞＞＞ 
XMLHttpRequestオブジェクトのなかにあるメソッドを使うとサーバとの通信ができるという事 でよさそうですね。 
このメソッドがサーバにinput内のテキストのみを送って、サーバがそれを受け取って、
inputないのテキストを加工してその加工データだけを送り返して、ブラウザ上でhtmlに組み込む。

Comment: 例えば検索画面を作るとします。検索ボタンが押されると入力エリアの値から `{"value": "あいう"}` の様な JSON を作成し、それをサーバに送ります。サーバはその value を見て検索を行い `{"result":["foo","bar","baz"]}` の様な結果を返します。その結果を JavaScript でパースしてテーブル表示します。これが Ajax を使った検索画面の例です。

Comment: やはりhtmlファイルをサーバが受け取って処理した結果を反映したhtmlファイルをクライアントに返すのではなく、
あくまでinput内のテキストのみを受け取って、それを処理した結果のテキストのみをクライアントに返すのですね。
htmlそのものだとそもそも部分的更新ではなく全体の更新になってしまうので、ajaxと矛盾してしまうのでおかしいなと思っていましたが、
この認識でだいたいよさそうですね。
ありがとうございました。